# Imported keys to electrum

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

I recently had an unconfirmed transaction on my btc qt wallet. I am upgrading my btc qt now and it is syncing. In the meantime I imported my keys from all my receiving addresses to a software wallet. I am still short my whole balance. Can someone explain this to me? Btc qt had X-an unconfirmed transaction. Now I have about X+half my unconfirmed transaction. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What did you actually import in Electrum? A master privatekey, or a list of private keys? 
In the first case, it could be that your gap limit (i.e. the addresses actively monitored by Electrum) is set too low, so it doesn't see some of your UTXOs. You can check this out :

`wallet.gap_limit`

Then increase the number you will see, for example if it tells you "20" try something like "50"

`wallet.change_gap_limit(50)`

`wallet.storage.write()`

Restart Electrum and see if your balance is back.